# ReactJS key not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Attempting to generate a table using ReactJS and within this table I want to have a unique key to identify each row (as recommended by ReactJS). The following code runs and generates the table I desire except with the following error:

```
Warning: 'Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop'
```

Looking at my generated HTML the 'key' field indeed does not exist. I've also tried key={index} but it doesn't work either

```
export class Tablecontent extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      fileinfo:'null'
    }
  }
  render(){
    //const fileinfo = this.props.rows;
    const fileinfo = ['myFile1.doc','myFile2.doc'];
    var row='';
    console.log("FILEINFO:"+fileinfo);
    if(fileinfo=='null')
    {
       row ='';
    }
    else {

     row = fileinfo.map((data,index) =>
    <tr>
      <td key="filename_{index}">{data}</td>
      <td key="date_{index}">2/12/2017</td>
      <td key="size_{index}">2.1 MB</td>
    </tr>
    );
  }
    return(
      <div>
        <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Date Created</th>
            <th>Size</th>
          </tr>{row}</tbody>
    </table>
      </div>
    );

  }
}
```

Resulting HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Date Created</th><th>Size</th></tr>
     <tr><td>myFile1.doc</td><td>2/12/2017</td><td>2.1 MB</td></tr>
    <tr><td>myFile2.doc</td><td>2/12/2017</td><td>2.1 MB</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: the key should be in the root element of your iterations

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It wants to see the key on the outer element returned in the map function as below.  The key is for React's internal use and won't display in the html.

```
 row = fileinfo.map((data,index) =>
    <tr key={index}>
      <td key="filename_{index}">{data}</td>
      <td key="date_{index}">2/12/2017</td>
      <td key="size_{index}">2.1 MB</td>
    </tr>
    );
```

Comment: That's probably right. My server just went down so I'll have to get it back up before I can response with a definite YES! Thank you